# Clustered file system on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, cluster

This is quite a general question but I need some advice on clustering apache linux servers ideally on VM.

I have some apache servers that are being using that are highly used on space (i.e. each server has 250gb of data on it) at the moment these are physical servers but I've built a VMware build to get away from the physical servers. My question is what is the best way to cluster different VM servers together ideally we have a data folder in the www root which is 150gb of data these folder I would like to be clustered?

I might be asking the wrong question but at the moment I'm rsyncing all data to a different server each night for a backup and clustering servers seems like the ideal way to go for performance.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Do you mean a SAN ?

Comment: I don't think that word means what you think it means.  Try asking the same question without the word 'cluster', because that can have specific meanings.

Comment: I've edited the title to attract the correct answers according to your question, and removed tags that didn't belong here. Update your answer like @pboin said, as this doesn't have anything to do with virtualization or server clustering. It's about file system clustering (or NAS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lustre or GlusterFS is Distributed parallel fault-tolerant file systems, which can 'group' each server's local disks via network to be presented as single entity.

Above is the solution to support concurrent read/write without shared block device,SAN/ISCSI.

The next step is to use load balancer to distribute load. e.g ha-proxy, LVS

If you have shared block device:SAN/ISCSI, try GFS on Red Hat Cluster Suite(both are free in Red Hat like distros).

Comment: Ceph is another cluster filesystem that can be interesting.